# vb.net Interpolated Strings

Tags: vb.net, string-interpolation

I was chastised by a professional developer with a lot of years of experience for Hard Coding my DB name
OK I get it we sometimes carry our bad codding habits with us till we learn the correct way to code
I have finally learned to use Interpolated Strings (personal view they are not pretty)

My Question involves the two Sub's posted below GetDB runs first then HowMany is called from GetDB
Sorry for stating the obvious my reason is I think that NewWord.db gets declared in GetDB and works in HowMany without the same construction Just a Wild Guess
Notice NO $ or quotation used in HowMany
Both Sub's produce desired results

**The question is Why don't both statements need to be constructed the same?**

```
    Public Sub HowMany()
    'Dim dbName As String = "NewWord.db"
    Dim conn As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source ='{NewWord.db}';Version=3;")
    tot = dgvOne.RowCount ' - 1
    tbMessage.Text = "DGV has " & tot.ToString & " Rows"
End Sub

Private Sub GetDB()

    Dim str2 As String
    Dim s1 As Integer
    'Dim dbName As String = "NewWord.db"
    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{"NewWord.db"}' ;Version=3;")
        conn.Open()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what `NewWord.db` is so I made a class to represent it.

```
Public Class NewWord
    Public Shared Property db As String = "The db Name"
End Class
```

`HowMany` is not a very good name for your sub. Try to use more descriptive names.

The first sub doesn't even use the connection. The connection string in that code is a literal string. It will not consider `NewWord.db` as a variable. You will not notice this because you never attempt to open the connection. In my version you check the connection string with a `Debug.Print`.

I changed the last line to use and interpolated string. It is not necessary to call `.ToString` on `tot`.

```
Private Sub DisplayGridCount()
    Dim conn As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source ='{NewWord.db}';Version=3;")
    Debug.Print(conn.ConnectionString)
    Dim tot = DataGridView1.RowCount
    TextBox1.Text = $"DGV has {tot} Rows"
End Sub
```

The second snippet starts off with 2 unused variables. I deleted them. Again, the `Debug.Print` to show the difference in the 2 strings.

```
Private Sub TestConnection()
    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{NewWord.db}' ;Version=3;")
        Debug.Print(conn.ConnectionString)
        'conn.Open()
    End Using
End Sub
```

As to where to store connection strings see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/protecting-connection-information and [Where to store Connection String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008616/where-to-store-connection-string)

Comment: NewWord.db is a String DB Name I agree HowMany not descriptive concentrating on code inhibits my naming Where I went wrong was I did not need to open a connection to DisplayGridCount AS YOU POINTED OUT I did learn how to store the DB name in App.config and retrieve it I see no Thanks Button these days so Thanks for the TestConnection SUB MY GetDB Sub reads records from DB to a Data Grid View

Answer (score 6):

That second method is a ridiculous and pointless use of string interpolation. What could possibly be the point of inserting a literal `String` into a literal `String`? The whole point is that you can insert values determined at run time. That second code is equivalent to using:

```vb
"Data Source = '" & "NewWord.db" & "' ;Version=3;"
```

What's the point of that? The idea is that you retrieve your database name from somewhere at run time, e.g. your config file, and then insert that into the template `String`, e.g.

```vb
Dim dbName = GetDbNameFromExternalFile()

Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{dbName}' ;Version=3;")
```

Now the user can edit that external file to change the database name after deploying the application. How could they change the name in your code?

To be clear, string interpolation is just native language support for the `String.Format` method. You can see that if you make a mistake that generates an exception and the that exception will refer to the `String.Format` method. In turn, `String.Format` is a way to make code that multiple values into a long template easier to read than if multiple concatenation operators were used.

Having lots of quotes and ampersands makes code hard to read and error-prone. I've lost count of the number of times people miss a single quote or a space or the like in a `String` because they couldn't read there messy code. Personally, I'll rarely use two concatenation operators in the same expression and never three. I'll do this:

```
Dim str = "some text" & someVar
```

but I'll rarely do this:

```
Dim str = "some text" & someVar & "some more text"
```

and I'll never do this:

```
Dim str = "some text" & someVar & "some more text" & someOtherVar
```

Before string interpolation, I would use `String.Format`:

```
Dim str = String.Format("some text{0}some more text{1}", someVar, someOtherVar)
```

Nowadays, I'll generally use string interpolation:

```
Dim str = $"some text{someVar}some more text{someOtherVar}"
```

Where I may still use `String.Format` over string interpolation is if one value is getting inserted in multiple places and/or where the text template and/or the expressions are long so that I can break the whole thing over multiple lines, e.g.

```
Dim str = String.Format("some text{0}some more text{1}yet more text{0}",
                        someVar,
                        someOtherVar)
```

Comment: OK so where do I store the DB name and what type of file a SQLite File? I created the DB and a Table when the app first runs The only other way I know to save a file is write a txt file to somewhere and that is the same non secure way of doing something Where is the config file?

Comment: *"where do I store the DB name"*. That's completely up to you. I provided one suggestion in the answer but that is really beyond the scope of this question. All that's relevant to this question is that you store it outside the application executable so that it can be modified without having to recompile the application.

Comment: *"what type of file a SQLite File"*. That's completely beyond the scope of this question. If you want to learn to use SQLite then there are plenty of places you can do that. That's nothing to do with string interpolation.

Comment: String.Format is also useful when you want to format your values:
    
    Dim elapsedTime As String = String.Format("{0:00}.{1:00} secs", ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10)